# Only replace first match with .replace

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that looks at a string of content & array of documents and finds any matches, then the user can accept or reject that match (another function). When the user accepts this match, see acceptLink function below, then I would like it to replace the first match and not all matches.

Example Content: "The first time I went home was when I went to see my dog at home."

Example Array: {name: 'Home', link: 'https://www.home.com/'}

**Expected output**: "The first time I went < a class="newLink"  href=https://www.home.com/>Home< / a > was when I went to see my dog at home."

```
const acceptLink = (a) => {
      var reg = new RegExp('('+a.name+')', 'gi');
      const aTag = '<a class="newLink"  href=' + a.link + '>' + a.name + '</a>'
      setContent(content.replace(reg, aTag));
      const replaceContent = content.replace(reg,aTag)
      const filtered = allLinks.filter(obj => {
      return obj.name !== a.name;
  });
```

Have I missed something here?

Comment: Is `a.name` supposed to be a regular expression (for example, what happens if user enters a dot)? If not, just skip the `new Regexp` part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `g`

```
const acceptLink = (a) => {
      var reg = new RegExp('('+a.name+')', 'i');
      const aTag = '<a class="newLink"  href=' + a.link + '>' + a.name + '</a>'
      setContent(content.replace(reg, aTag));
      const replaceContent = content.replace(reg,aTag)
      const filtered = allLinks.filter(obj => {
      return obj.name !== a.name;
  });
```